# What is the right preposition in the sentence?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I am not sure what preposition I need to use in following sentence:

> Standard places for labeling **of** administrative department stickers

It's a title so it is not put in some context. I doubt whether I should use ***with*** instead of ***of***. But in the same time of sounds right for me (because it is a title and *stickers* are the subject) 
I need clarifying of someone who knows how it should be exactly.

Comment: The answer isn't quite as clear as it was made out. Depending on context, you *do* label stickers. If the machine is one in which you program in a price or word, you are providing a label to the sticker and then attaching the labelled sticker to something. Annoyingly, the same word applies to both things. You can label the stickers *and* you can label the things you are applying the stickers to with the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stickers are the labels in question, not something being labeled. So you wouldn't use **of** but **with**.

> We have rules for the labeling of equipment **with** stickers.

In your phrase you do not identify what things are having labels placed on them. It seems to be a heading or caption. It's not a full sentence in any case.

The noun phrase "administrative department stickers" is also odd.  It is not clear how either a sticker or a department can be "administrative".

Comment: Yes, I wrote that it is a title. That's why it is not full. And you are right it's administration department stickers.

Comment: Anyway it sounds weird to me. *"Places for labeling with stickers"*. Maybe there are no need in any preposition? Just *"Places for labeling stickers"*?

Comment: No, do you not label stickers.  The stickers are the labels. *Label* is a transitive verb. You "label equipment". You "label stuff".  The preposition **with** introduces the means of adding the label.  *He labeled the leftovers container with a sharpie.*  *She labeled the box with a pre-printed sticker.*

Comment: Your recurrent issue is that you seem to be aiming for a bureaucratic register when simpler language would suffice.  For example: *Where to place asset-tracking labels*. or *Asset-tracking labeling standards*.

Comment: You're right. I will make it simpler. Thank you for clarifying for me the function of the verb *label*!